# Google Apps login in wordpress

Tags: user-registration, openid

I manage a google apps domain with plenty of users;

I would like to join Google apps with a Wordpress based intranet app we're creating.

Which level of integration could I expect to achieve?

Our hope is to create users in wordpress using their google apps email and let them login using their google apps password, so that they don't need to remember two different passwords.

How would you suggest we should implement this?

Comment: Actually I found a plugin that use google identity toolkit to do exactly what I need, but is still quite bugged :( Sometimes it gives errors on login or it ask to set a password when adding new users even if the plugin eliminates the password field in the Add new user process...
It's a pity, it was exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the plugin Wordpress Social Login:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-social-login/

Does exactly what you want except the user doesn't actually have to type in their username and password if they are already logged in to Google Apps - they just click the Google icon and it will log them in to WordPress using Google Apps.

And yes, you can create users in WordPress first tied to Google Apps email addresses and then the users can login without needing a registration step.

It provides other auth options (FB, Twitter, etc.) if you'd like.

Comment: Hello, I'm pretty satisfied with the plugin but I've got one problem. Anyone can register using google and the admin cannot do anything to block this registrations. Even if you cancel these new users it will reappear at the next login attempt. 

Is not possible to allow signing only from already chosen address or make the user wait until his request is accepted?

Comment: What I did was modify the code to wrap the login in the following: 

 if(get_option('users_can_register')) {
  //main social login code here
 }

This makes the plugin respect the WordPress general setting regarding whether or not users can register, rather than auto-registering any user that comes to your site.

Comment: I thought about this and i resolved that i prefer not to edit the plugin code, to be upgrade safe. I decided instead to redirect every registered users with subscriber role to a page in which they have to choose their role and be accepted by an administrator. If they don't choose their role, they will be cancelled automatically in, let say, 10 days. What do you think about this? (hwr is a bit a shame for this plugin to ignore the user_can_register option!)

Answer (score 4):

This question was asked a while ago, but for anyone else facing this problem, we have developed a plugin that allows users to login using the latest Google OAuth2 without needing a separate WordPress password.

Google Apps Login is designed specifically for intranets (or any WordPress site) where the organization is running their email entirely on Google Apps.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-apps-login/

The plugin is fully supported, through support licenses and a premium version which can save you a lot of time on user management - domain admins no longer need to separately manage WordPress user accounts.

Comment: Is their a way to register the user if email is not present?

Comment: Manoj, not in the free version, no, but the Premium/Enterprise versions we offer have many facilities for user management like that.

Answer (score 2):

I would say Using [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) would be your best bet. Making it so that the users can login only with gmail by removing all the WordPress registration and login.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/oauth-provider/

Comment: Thanks!

One question about it: Can I create the users on wordpress and then bind them to their google apps account or they have to sign up by themselves the first time?

This because there won't be any sign up option, but only the log in form for already registered user, that are put manually by us (even better would be to automagically import users from our google apps domain, but i guess that would be too much!)

Comment: Uhm, this plugin looks more like it makes me a OAuth provider than let people log in my site with their google apps accounts.